# Quantiles of normal distribution transformed

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, quantiles

Let $Y_1 \sim N(2,1)$ and $Y_2 \sim N(5,(\frac{1}{2})^2)$. Let $X = Y_1+Y_2$. The mean and variance of $X$ can easily be computed to 7 and $1/4+1$. How do I determine the quantiles?

$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent and each iid sequence.

Comment: You haven't told us whether $Y_1$ is independent of $Y_2$. To get 5/4 for the variance requires independence. Otherwise you need to include the covariance term.

Comment: Do you know how to determine quantiles for a standard Normal distribution?  Indeed, could you tell us more specifically what you mean by "determine" here?  Would it mean "look up," "call a statistical function," "compute by hand," "approximate," or something else?

Comment: I mean "compute by hand"

Comment: Nobody does that because it's an incredible amount of effort--even a computer uses an iterative root-finding procedure and numerical quadrature--but you can come up with fairly accurate approximations.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume independence, $X$ would be distributed $N$(7,5/4). Then you can get the quantiles by computing the cumulative normal distribution from $-\infty$ to $x$ where that integral is equal to the percentage associated with the required quantile and $x$ would be the value of that quantile.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the comments and trying to expand a bit over M.R.Chernick's answer, assuming $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent, we have that

$$X \sim  N\left(7, 1\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

Let $x_p$ be the desired $p$th quantile of $X$ and let $z_p$ be the $p$th quantile of the standard normal distribution, for any $p\in (0,1)$. Then
$$x_p = 7 + \sqrt{1\frac{1}{4}}z_p.\tag{*}$$

**R example**

Say we want to compute $x_{0.123}$. In `R` you can do

```
> qnorm(0.123, mean=7, sd=sqrt(5/4))
[1] 5.702947
```

or using (*) we can do

```
> 7 + sqrt(5/4)*qnorm(0.123)
[1] 5.702947
```